# laravel Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator error in artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

**I use `php artisan` command but I see this error.**

**this error show in all artisan commands**

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Reque   
      st, null given, called in E:\appoo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php
      on line 65
```

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Please make sure that you are not using any `url()` or `asset()` or other helpers functions inside your configuration files

Comment: thanks resolved problem. i used from url() in package config file.

Comment: Nice to hear that it worked

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure that you are not using any **url()** or **asset()** or other helpers functions inside your configuration files

Comment: you really helped me ! but can you please explain the problem ? i could not find another way to configure my local system except using url( ) helper

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are not using any `url()` or `asset()` or other helpers functions inside your configuration files , in my case in the services.php file, I changed this

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => url('auth/google/callback'),
],
```

To this

```
 'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => Config('app.url').'auth/google/callback',
],
```